# Removing an object at a NSMutableArray causes a crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray

Attempting to remove an object at a NSMutableArray causes a crash:

```
 2014-03-07 18:58:03.755 HomeWork Pro +[12637:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI removeObjectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa2f4c20'
```

remove object code:

```
[hwArray removeObjectAtIndex:self.indexPath.row];
```

This only happens if I do it with self.indexPath.row, if I do it with a number it functions normally. I know the self.indexPath.row is not nil, I've NSlogged it to be sure and it turnde right. After doing that I do

```
[table reloadData]
```

to reload the UITableView data and the methods.
Any clue on what's the issue here?
Call stack

```
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x017aa5e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0152d8b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
2   CoreFoundation                      0x01847903 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
3   CoreFoundation                      0x0179a90b ___forwarding___ + 1019
4   CoreFoundation                      0x0179a4ee _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
5   HomeWork Pro +                      0x00006c88 -[HomeWork SelfDelete] + 216
6   HomeWork Pro +                      0x0000711a -[HomeWork done:] + 618
7   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0153f874 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 77
8   UIKit                               0x0029d0c2 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 108
9   UIKit                               0x0029d04e -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 61
10  UIKit                               0x003950c1 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 66
11  UIKit                               0x00395484 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 577
12  UIKit                               0x00394733 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 641
13  UIKit                               0x002da51d -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 852
14  UIKit                               0x002db184 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 1232
15  UIKit                               0x002aee86 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 242
16  UIKit                               0x0029918f _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 11421
17  CoreFoundation                      0x0173383f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
18  CoreFoundation                      0x017331cb __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 235
19  CoreFoundation                      0x0175029e __CFRunLoopRun + 910
20  CoreFoundation                      0x0174fac3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
21  CoreFoundation                      0x0174f8db CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
22  GraphicsServices                    0x023349e2 GSEventRunModal + 192
23  GraphicsServices                    0x02334809 GSEventRun + 104
24  UIKit                               0x0029bd3b UIApplicationMain + 1225
25  HomeWork Pro +                      0x00008bad main + 141
26  libdyld.dylib                       0x02c8a70d start + 1
27  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: In which delegate did you put that line of code

Comment: @meda it's in an IBAction wich is triggered when you click a button subviewed in a table cell

Comment: No, you're attempting to create an NSArray with a null object pointer.

Comment: (Show the exception stack trace.)

Comment: @HotLicks Stack trace in the edit

Comment: So, what is in the SelfDelete method?

Comment: looks like a duplicate to: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9452952/nsinvalidargumentexception-when-deleting-cell-using-a-different-class][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9452952/nsinvalidargumentexception-when-deleting-cell-using-a-different-class

Comment: hwArray should be NSMutableArray instead of NSArray

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like the crash message you posted and your stack trace do not match. The stack trace shows an "unrecognized selector" crash in the making, but the crash message shows that you were attempting to insert a nil object into an array.

Neither of those things matches the line of code that you posted. (removing an object from an array.) I guess you could get an unrecognized selector error from the line of source you posted if the array wasn't really a mutable array...

EDIT:

Based on your updated question, it's clear. Your array is not actually a mutable array even though you think it is.

Post the code that creates the array.

If you're copying it somewhere, look at that code carefully. If you're loading it from a plist or an archive, be aware that mutable arrays come back as immutable when you read them back in.

Answer (score 1):

What you have is an immutable NSArray. What you want is an NSMutableArray, which actually does implement `removeObjectAtIndex:`. Make sure your array isn't getting replaced with an immutable version at some point.